# pytesseract can't detect digit and operators

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, captcha, python-tesseract

I want to extract two digits and an operator (e.g. 14 + 23) from an image, but this script that I wrote, won't work:

```
import cv2 as cv
import pytesseract

img = cv.imread('VerificationImage.jpg')
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))

conf = r'--oem 3 --psm 11 outputbase digits'
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, config=conf)

for x, b in enumerate(boxes.splitlines()):
    if x != 0:
        b = b.split()
        print(b)
        if len(b) == 12:
            x, y, w, h = int(b[6]), int(b[7]), int(b[8]), int(b[9])
            cv.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 120, 0), 2)
        


cv.imshow("display", img)
cv.waitKey()
```

The sample image is like this:
[image: The sample image]

Comment: it's a CAPTCHA, it's not supposed to work. I'd say it serves its purpose here.

Comment: I realised that tesseract is not helping in this kind of problem, instead, we should train our OCR ourselves. Thank you

Comment: @Milo did you try analyzing in a different color space?